# jquery dialog in asp.net initialise dialog with serverside call

Tags: .net, jquery, dialog

I'm really trying to get to grips with this jquery.

What i want to do is load a jquery dialog but before it loads i need to do some server side processing and bind a datalist inside the dialog.

I have know idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For making a server call, you should use one of the ajax functions (http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax). You can then implement callback function which opens the dialog (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Answer (score 0):

You could also load an url in the dialog box. This url could be another asp.net page.